# sequence of bounded domain in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider 
$$\Omega_1 \supset \Omega_2 \supset \cdots$$
a sequence of bounded, open and convex domains in $\mathbb R^n$, with all the inclusions strict. I want to prove that $\bigcap \Omega_k \subset \overline{\bigcap \Omega_k}  \subset \Omega_k$ for all $k$.
I believe this is true. In some cases is easy to see this. but i dont know how to prove . Someone can give me a hint to how to prove or disprove ?
the problem is the second inclusion

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "$\cap\Omega_k$ do you mean $\bigcap_k\Omega_k$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy , yes  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second inclusion is sometimes false.  E.g. in $\mathbb R$, $\Omega_k=(0,1+1/k)$.

Answer (score 1):

As for the first inclusion, it is obviously *weakly* true, since every set is included in its closure by definition. But the inclusion need not be *strict*. Let, for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $\Omega_k\equiv(-1/k,1/k)$. Then, the intersection $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_+}\Omega_k$ is $\{0\}$, which is a closed set, so that it is equal to its closure.